# Visual studio view (.cshtml) crashed and cannot recover

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, web

My view file(.cshtml) crashed and turned into as shown in image below. Actually, it happened right after the system was unexpectedly shut down. I tried other solutions like clearing temp files from bin. I tried to open it with notepad++ but it didn't work. 
Any help will be appreciated.[image]

Answer (score 1):

Download [WinHex](http://www.winhex.com/winhex/hex-editor.html) program and open your corrupted file with it.

1. Go: Tools > Open Disk
2. Navigate to your corrupted file
3. Double click on it

If there is [non-zero values](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y3uHE.png), just copy and paste all this data to you new file.

Comment: dude, you just saved my life! :)

Comment: What if there is not any "non zero values"?

Comment: If you see just 00 00 00 00 00 00 in whole document (WinHex), it means 'no data' and file can't be recovered.

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid you've lost it.

If you have a VCS in place (which you should), restore the file from there. Also, see if there are any [previous versions](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/previous-versions-files-faq#1TC=windows-7) of the file and try to fish it out from over there. Lastly, check your general-purpose backups, if you happen to have those.

Comment: I am afraid to say that I have two days old backup. But within 2 days I've lots of changes in it.

Answer (score 0):

If you have published your content, then in visual studio you can right click on the specific file and choose 'replace [fileName] from server'. This will download an uncorrupted version of your content from the published site.

Hope this helps.